# Framework7 external links close issue

Tags: javascript, html-framework-7

I have a weird issue with external links in Framework7
I want the panel to close after click the external link , but its wont.

```
<a href="/buttons/" class="link external panel-close">Buttons</a>
```

Is there another way to close the panel after click on this link?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it with Jquery

```
$('.external').on('click', function () {
            $('.panel').animate({"right":"-500px"}, "fast");
         });
```